# show only two digit after decimal in angularjs for input?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new in `Angular`.
Anyone can tell me that how can I achieve this.

```
$scope.var1 = 125.548765;
$scope.var2 = 125.54
```

I want to calculate value with the `var1` but I want to show on screen same as `var2`.
If I use `ng-model` then its reflect both side. so tell me how can I do this.
I want to use this value in angular datatable.

Answer (score 4):

In your template you can use it like this:

```
{{ var1 | number:2 }}
```

You can also use this filter in Javascript:

```
$filter('number')($scope.var1, 2);
```

This is a basic filter in AngularJs. You can find more information here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number

Comment: but how can i use this in datatable? I want to show data in datatable.

Comment: but tell me how to use filter('number') in angular datatable

Comment: Update your question. Your question says nothing about any datatable. There is no example of your datatable.

Answer (score 1):

create custom directive and return value same as I want.

```
app.directive('myModel', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController){
            ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(value){
                return Math.round(value*100)/100;
            })
        }
    }
});
```

[example here for custom directive](http://plnkr.co/edit/9vtmnw?p=preview)